# Merge objects in an based on a common key/value

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have this input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "color": "red",
    "job": "plumber",
    "version": "5.2.4",
    "description": "Plumber john likes his job",
    "contact": "true"
  },
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "color": "green",
    "job": "electrician",
    "version": "7.3.9",
    "description": "Electrician Bob is unhappy",
    "contact": "true"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the output of:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "12345",
        "color" : "red",
        "color" : "green",
        "job" : "plumber",
        "job" : "electrician",
        "version" : "5.2.4",
        "version" : "7.3.9",
        "description" : "Plumber john likes his job",
        "description" : "Electrician Bob is unhappy",
        "contact" : "true"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to make sure that when the merge occurs off the key of id that any key-value pair that is the same isn't duplicated, but if the key-value pair differs then that will be displayed/merged.  For instance  above the color has a value of red and green of which I want it to be merged in while contact is true for both so no need to duplicate on the merge.

I'm using the following JOLT to group all the values, but the final output is something I'm not able to achieve.

JOLT:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id": {
            "*": {
              "@2": "&[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&"
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi rsnyder, the expected output is not a valid JSON, since the identical attribute keys are repeated.

Comment: Hello! Are you saying that if the key is the same but the value differs, it's not valid?  I figured this was a long shot to JOLT but didn't know if it was doable or not.

Comment: Yes I've meant that